# Why is the .get() function of tkinter returing an empty string

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

Basically I want to run a code that allows the user to change their credentials(already given at the start). Over here the functions- def Uname_change(), def Password_change(), def PhoneNo_change() and def DOB_change() tries to do that.

But the variable 'a' in each of these function(a is got from the get() function on the various entry widgets as shown) yields an empty string. I'm not able to understand why.

Code:

```py
class ProfilePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = 'light blue')

        def show_profile():
          
            def Uname_change():
                Uname_change_window = tk.Tk()
                label = tk.Label(Uname_change_window, text = 'Enter New UserName').pack()
                NewUname = tk.StringVar()
                entry = tk.Entry(Uname_change_window, textvariable = NewUname).pack()
                confirm_button = tk.Button(Uname_change_window, text='Confirm', command= ).pack()
                back_button = tk.Button(Uname_change_window, text='Back', command= lambda : Uname_change_window.destroy()).pack()
                Uname_change_window.mainloop()
                


            def Password_change():
                Password_change_window = tk.Tk()
                label = tk.Label(Password_change_window, text = 'Enter New Password').pack()
                NewPassword = tk.StringVar()
                entry = tk.Entry(Password_change_window, textvariable = NewPassword).pack()
                def confirm():
                    a = NewPassword.get()
                    print(a)
                    #Write code for updation of database
                    Password_change_window.destroy()
                confirm_button = tk.Button(Password_change_window, text='Confirm', command= confirm).pack()
                back_button = tk.Button(Password_change_window, text='Back', command= lambda : Password_change_window.destroy()).pack()
                
                

            def PhoneNo_change():
                PhoneNo_change_window = tk.Tk()
                label = tk.Label(PhoneNo_change_window, text = 'Enter New PhoneNumber').pack()
                NewPhoneNo = tk.StringVar()
                entry = tk.Entry(PhoneNo_change_window, textvariable = NewPhoneNo).pack()
                def confirm():
                    a = NewPhoneNo.get()
                    print(a)
                    #Write code for updation of database
                    PhoneNo_change_window.destroy()
                confirm_button = tk.Button(PhoneNo_change_window, text='Confirm', command= confirm).pack()
                back_button = tk.Button(PhoneNo_change_window, text='Back', command= lambda : PhoneNo_change_window.destroy()).pack()
                
                

            def DOB_change():
                DOB_change_window = tk.Tk()
                label = tk.Label(DOB_change_window, text = 'Enter New DateOfBirth').pack()
                NewDOB = tk.StringVar()
                entry = tk.Entry(DOB_change_window, textvariable = NewDOB).pack()
                def confirm():
                    a = NewDOB.get()
                    print(a)
                    #Write code for updation of database
                    DOB_change_window.destroy()
                confirm_button = tk.Button(DOB_change_window, text='Confirm', command= confirm).pack()
                back_button = tk.Button(DOB_change_window, text='Back', command= lambda : DOB_change_window.destroy()).pack()
                
                
            
            UserID_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'UserID').grid(row=2,column=0)
            Uname_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'UserName').grid(row=3,column=0)
            Uname_change_button = tk.Button(self, text = 'Edit', command = Uname_change).grid(row=3,column=2)#
            Password_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Password').grid(row=4,column=0)
            Password_change_button = tk.Button(self, text = 'Edit', command = Password_change).grid(row=4,column=2)#
            PhoneNo_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'PhoneNo').grid(row=5,column=0)
            PhoneNo_change_button = tk.Button(self, text='Edit', command = PhoneNo_change).grid(row=5,column=2)#
            DOB_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'DateOfBirth').grid(row=6,column=0)
            DOB_change_button = tk.Button(self, text = 'Edit', command = DOB_change).grid(row=6,column=2)#
            DOJ_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'DateOfJoining').grid(row=7,column=0)                      
        show_button = tk.Button(self, text = 'Show', command = show_profile).grid(row=1,column=1)
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down, and make it so that it runs. As it stands now there are some syntax errors. If you're seeing the same behavior from multiple functions, for the purposes of this question we only need one function.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is both that you're using local variables for the entry widgets, and you're using more than one instance of Tk.

If you need to create multiple windows, you should use `Toplevel` not `Tk` for every window other than the root window. That is because each instance of `Tk` gets a new internal tcl interpreter. Widgets and variables from one cannot be seen by another.

Also, since you aren't using any of the features of the tkinter variables (tracing, sharing between widgets), you don't need to use them at all. You can simply call the `get` method of the entry widget. That solves the problem of using a local variable, and it's just one less object your code has to manage.

Here's how I would rewrite the first few lines of

```
def PhoneNo_change():
    PhoneNo_change_window = tk.Toplevel()
    label = tk.Label(PhoneNo_change_window, text = 'Enter New PhoneNumber')
    entry = tk.Entry(PhoneNo_change_window)
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()
    def confirm():
        a = entry.get())
        print(f"a is '{a}'")
        ...
```

... though honestly, you need to refactor all of that duplicate code into a single function.